# spotify ios sdk contentAPI fetchChildrenOfContentItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, spotify

I recently started to use this SDK and I realized that whenever I try to fetch one playlist tracks, the call to the method will always fetch the first 20 items, regardless of the playlist I have given it to as parameter. I cannot find in the documentation a way to retrieve the next 20 tracks and so on.

Could you please help me sort this out?

Many thanks.

```
[[self appRemote].contentAPI fetchRootContentItemsForType:SPTAppRemoteContentTypeDefault callback:^(id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        [[PPLoader sharedLoader] HideHudLoader];
        if(error!=nil) {
            return;
        }
        NSArray *array = (NSArray*)result;
        NSLog(@"context title: %@", self.playerState.contextTitle);
        for (id<SPTAppRemoteContentItem>item in array) {
            if ([item.title  isEqual: @"Your Library"]) {

                [[self appRemote].contentAPI fetchChildrenOfContentItem:item callback:^(id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if(error!=nil) {
                        return;
                    }
                    for (id<SPTAppRemoteContentItem>item2 in (NSArray*)result) {
                        if ([item2.title  isEqual: @"Playlists"]) {

                            [[self appRemote].contentAPI fetchChildrenOfContentItem:item2 callback:^(id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                if (error!= nil) {
                                    return;
                                }
                                for(id<SPTAppRemoteContentItem> item3 in (NSArray*)result) {
                                    NSLog(@"item3.title=%@ and self.playerState.contextTitle=%@", item3.title, self.playerState.contextTitle);
                                    if([item3.title isEqualToString:self.playerState.contextTitle]) {
                                        playlist = item3;
                                        [[self appRemote].contentAPI fetchChildrenOfContentItem:playlist callback:^(id  _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                            if (error != nil) {
                                                return;
                                            }
                                            //arrMusicList = (NSMutableArray*)result;
                                            [arrMusicList addObjectsFromArray:(NSMutableArray*)result];

                                            compBlock(YES);
                                            [tblList reloadData];
                                        }];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }];

                        }

                    }

                }];
                break;
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: please share the code related to fetchChildrenOfContentItem

Comment: Done! Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Actually Even I stuck some where thats why if you share your code or add demo in GitHub that would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. 
There is an issue entered in github, that says, it is limited to 20 results. :-(

https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/172

Let me know, once you know a workaround.